# JS uploader allowing me to select the folder

Tags: javascript, uploader

I'm looking for a JS uploader (free or commercial) that lets me select the folder (on the server) where to upload the file.

I will be uploading single files most of the time.

I tried FineUploader and DropZone, plus various GitHub projects, but none of then offer this ability.

Comment: You're aware that Javascript runs client-side and thus cannot let you browse folders on the server – unless it knows all available directories beforehand (i.e. at the time the script is downloaded by the clients browser)?

Comment: @Izzy they have back-end part.. There are tons of scripts

Comment: That's what I meant: it cannot be done by a client-side Javascript alone. Would the server part use Javascript as well, or would other solutions be acceptable too? What requirements must be met on the server? (PS: Your answer shows I was correct: the product you chose requires PHP on the server)

Answer (score 1):

I meet **[elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder),** a free JS file manager with folder support. It allow drag'n'drop upload, browsing folders, CRUD operations on files and folders.

On server side, it requires PHP 5.2+ (recommended is PHP 5.4 or higher). Easy installation with composer.